# Angular on prod - how to see what packages are used (w/o npm)

Tags: node.js, angular

I dont want to install npm or nodejs on prod linux. it currently runs an asp.net core app.
I want to check whether it is using a specific package (postcss).

In dev environment I can see multiple postcss folders in `node_modules` folder.

Thats easy. But in prod there is only `dist` folder with compressed js files.

I grepped them and could not find any `postcss` string in it. But I am not sure if that is correct way to do it.

For example there is also no `devkit` string anywhere in .js files but there is license terms for `@angular-devkit/built-angular` in `dist/3rdpartylicenses.txt` - which begs the question - why would it need to keep license of a package which is not used.

And postcss is one of devkit dependencies..

So in short - *how to make sure there is not even a slightest trace of postcss on a machine without `npm` ?*

Answer (score 0):

No way. Why you don't want to use npm? For its move have to builder analizator.

```
npm install -g webpack-bundle-analyzer
```

Look at that: https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/optimize-angular-bundle-size-in-4-steps-4a3b3737bf45